# How to use FQL in Graph API explorer? I have looked for solutions at various places but no one has explained it clearly

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Even the basic query - GET /fql?q=SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me() is giving the following error -

"message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ",

Answer (score 0):

? For FQL just choose  FQL Query instead of  Graph API in the top of the page.